# How to use ggplot2 to create a stacked bar chart of three variables (not categories!)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a dataframe with data of the daily evolution of the coronavirus with 4 columns: date, active cases, deaths and recoveries. 
Since the sum of these 3 last values is equal to the total number of cases, I want a bar chart where each day has a corresponding bar divided in 3 parts: active cases, deaths and recoveries. 
How do I do this with ggplot? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to reshape your dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` function for example in order to fit the use with `ggplot2`.

As an example with a fake dataset:

```r
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"),ymd("2020-01-10"),by = "day"),
                 active = sample(10:100,10),
                 death = sample(10:100,10),
                 recov = sample(10:100,10))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "case", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(case = factor(case, levels = c("active","recov","death"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = val, fill = case))+
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset by following this guide: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the code you have try so far.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but the pivot_longer function is not being recognized:

> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(ggplot2)
> data %>% pivot_longer(-Data, names_to = "Total", values_to = "NúmeroDeCasos") %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = Data, y = NúmeroDeCasos, fill = Total))+
+   geom_col()
Error in pivot_longer(., -Data, names_to = "Total", values_to = "NúmeroDeCasos") : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer"

Comment: I also tried "remotes::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")" to no avail

Comment: What versions of R, dplyr, ggplot2, tidyr are you using ?

Comment: R - 3.6.1
tidyr_0.8.3
dplyr_0.8.0.1
lubridate_1.7.4
ggplot2_3.1.1

Comment: `pivot_longer` have benn introduced in `tidyr 1.0.0`, so you need to upgrade `tidyr`. Restart your session and pass `install.packages("tidyr")`. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html

Comment: Perfect. One last thing: I can't change the order of the stacking: 
the order it is giving me is recoveries, deaths, active but I want active cases on the bottom, then recoveries, then deaths on top. I tried changing the order of the dataframe I was feeding to the function but that seems to have no effect on the order of the stacking. Do you know how I could solve that?
Thank you for everything

Comment: Current code (but feel free to use your code for simplicity sake):
plotdata <- data[,c("Data", "Ativos", "Recuperados", "Óbitos")]
plotdata %>% pivot_longer(-Data, names_to = "Total", values_to = "NúmeroDeCasos") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Data, y = NúmeroDeCasos, fill = Total))+
  geom_col()

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly it. Thank you so much

Comment: do you know how to change the title and text in the label? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use `labs` to change title and x and y axis: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html